# Bus Manifest Summary Page Formula (List Buses With Open Seats)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am creating a manifest roster for buses. I have a worksheet that includes names, a bus number, destination, and start/end date. Let's say each bus has three seats, and if there is space available, the name cell is empty.

```
WORKSHEET: "Manifest"
name      bus #   location       start date     end date
missy     1       new york       2020/10/01     2020/10/10
ralph     1       new york       2020/10/01     2020/10/10
[empty]   1       new york       2020/10/01     2020/10/10
frank     2       philadelphia   2020/10/15     2020/10/25
[empty]   2       philadelphia   2020/10/15     2020/10/25
[empty]   2       philadelphia   2020/10/15     2020/10/25
ryan      3       pittsburgh     2020/11/01     2020/11/10
jim       3       pittsburgh     2020/11/01     2020/11/10
[empty]   3       pittsburgh     2020/11/01     2020/11/10
kate      4       detroit        2020/11/15     2020/11/28
joe       4       detroit        2020/11/15     2020/11/28
martha    4       detroit        2020/11/15     2020/11/28
```

I need to push this to another worksheet with a quick summary of how many seats are available for each bus:

```
WORKSHEET: "Dashboard"
bus #   location       start date     end date      open seats
1       new york       2020/10/01     2020/10/10    1
2       philadelphia   2020/10/15     2020/10/25    2
3       pittsburgh     2020/11/01     2020/11/10    1
```

Note: The dashboard would not include any buses that do not have seats.

The formula that I'm trying to figure out, would need to only show buses with seats open, list the bus number/location/start/end, and count how many blank cells are listed for that bus.

After a solid day of building out this worksheet and dashboard, this is the remaining piece I have been banging my head on. I am running Excel 2016, so that would rule out any Office 365 updates. Since it's a clean dashboard, the formula would need to include IFERROR to not print "#N/A" to any cells.

Not sure if it's end of the day and end of the work week, but I just can't figure this out. Coming up short with existing Stack Overflow questions. Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the goal would be to create a `Pivot`:

1. Insert a `Pivot table`
2. Add the `bus`, `location` and `dates` fields to the `Pivot` rows
3. Add a `bus` field to the `Pivot` values. In `Value field settings` choose `Summarize values by` `Count`
4. Add a `name` field to the `Pivot` filter
5. Go to `PivotTable Options` -> `Display` tab and place a check at the `Classic PivotTable layout` chekbox
6. Filter out blank `names`
7. Done.

[image]

However, if you still want to do it with formulas, then you can use the following:

1. for `bus` column

   if type is number:

   `=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$13/(($A$2:$A$13="")*(COUNTIF($I$1:I1,$B$2:$B$13)=0)),1),"-")`

   if type is text:

   `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13;AGGREGATE(15;6;(1/(($A$2:$A$13="")*(COUNTIF($I$1:I1;$B$2:$B$13)=0)))*ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1;1));"-")`
2. for `location` column

   `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$13=I2)*($A$2:$A$13=""),$C$2:$C$13),"-")`
3. for `start date` column

   `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$13=I2)*($A$2:$A$13=""),$D$2:$D$13),"-")`
4. for `end date` column

   `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$13=I2)*($A$2:$A$13=""),$E$2:$E$13),"-")`
5. for `open seats` column

   `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$13=I2)*($A$2:$A$13=""))`

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use the formula for the `bus` column if the data was text, not a number? The LOOKUP formula was the missing link and your answer is solid gold.

Comment: If the data in the 'bus' column is text, then add the ```INDEX``` function to the formula. See edit.